# ubuntu上でrubyをビルド中に止まってしまう

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu

ubuntu上でruby on railsをビルドしているのですが、いつも同じところでビルドが止まってしまいます。以下の「ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:319:in `block in create_worker'」のところです。

```
/home/****/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.0.5/lib/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:320:in `loop'
/home/****/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.0.5/lib/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:320:in `block (2 levels) in create_worker'
/home/****/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.0.5/lib/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:319:in `catch'
/home/****/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.0.5/lib/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:319:in `block in create_worker'
```

環境は次のとおりです。
- ubuntu16.04
- rubyは2.5.0をインストールしたのに2.4.2になっているのが気になります

インストールしたものは、次のとおりです。

- libcurl4-gnutls-dev
- ruby-dev
- libxml2-dev
- libxslt-dev
- tzdata
- libghc-yaml-dev
- postgresql
- less

他に必要な情報がありましたら、ご連絡ください。
それでは、よろしくお願いします。

Comment: rbenv使ってinstallしてはいかが？

Comment: エラーメッセージはこれだけですか？

Comment: rbenv install 2.4.1などを使ってinstallしています。

Comment: エラーメッセージと思しきものはありません。ビルド（run）が止まってしまうのです。